# How to find file on classpath in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

Sometimes I will meet some issue which is caused by classpath. Is there any tool or plugin in eclipse that can help me find files in the current project's classpath ? Go through the Referenced library in eclipse is not so efficient , wondering any other alternatives ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you want, but you can try the following:

1. enable "link with editor" [image: the two yellow arrows] in package explorer
2. open the desired class by pressing F3 when the cursor is on the class name in one of your source files

   [image: e.g. String.class]
3. this will open the source of the given class (or the class file if no source is attached) and shows the respective file in the package explorer:

   [image]

If you are not currently using the class you can simply type the package and name of the class into your code temporarily using auto-completion. Then hit F3 to see where the class is located...

Answer (score -1):

You can use the "Open Resource" shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>).

Comment: Yes but this doesn't search in referenced jars.

Comment: The "Open Resource" shortcut searches in your files, but does *not* search in your classpath.

Answer (score -1):

```
Shortcut is cntrl+shift+R
```

You can also customize shortcut keys for that

Comment: Yes but this doesn't search in referenced jars.

Comment: The "Open Resource" shortcut searches in your files, but does not search in your classpath.